# How to get all the words to be in a single line while displaying in a Listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying  to display all the strings to be in a single line, but it is showing two words in each line. Here is my code:

```vb
For i = 0 To readCount - 1
  ListBox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Add(readBuffer(i).ToString("X2")) & vbCrLf
Next
```

[image]

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to do? What's in your `readBuffer`? What's with the `.ToString("X2")`?

Comment: I am trying to read a message which is in the form of Hexa decimal and trying to display that message in the text box in a single line. But, I am getting two hexadecimals in each line. .ToString("x2") is used to convert the number to hexadecimal

Comment: What do you mean by "getting two hexadecimals in each line". Can you maybe post a screenshot?

Comment: @StanBruce, Please check the picture in my main message. Click on "enter image description here"

Comment: I only see 1 hexadecimal value per line. 18, for example, got converted from 24 (using `.ToString("X2")`).

Comment: yea, sorry one hexadecimal. So, how can I make that to display in a single line?

Comment: So you want all the values as a single item in your ListBox? Like "18004F9BBE0E..."?

Comment: Correct. @ Stan Bruce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a **[StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)** to join the hexadecimal values first. Then add them to the ListBox.

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

For i = 0 To readCount - 1
    sb.Append(readBuffer(i).ToString("X2"))
Next

ListBox1.Items.Add(sb.ToString)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. @ Stan Bruce

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a line break, than don't use the `& vbCrlf` part, since that part is responsible for adding the line break between (after, actually) every item.

```
For i = 0 To readCount - 1
    ListBox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Add(readBuffer(i).ToString("X2"))
Next
```

Comment: Even after removig &vbCrlf, I am not getting in a single line. Is there any other way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

[`vbCrLf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf(v=vs.110).aspx) is a constant that represents *Carriage Return* and *Line Feed*. Those are special chars evaluating to a newline.

Just take away the concatenation with `vbCrLf`. Your string should be single-line then. (Except for, when one of the input strings contains `vbCrLf` itself.

Comment: Even after removig &vbCrlf, I am not getting in a single line.